# RPI Pico put PNG in Framebuffer

Tags: png, framebuffer, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a Raspberry pi pico w with a PNG file on it and i am wondering if its possible to put this PNG file inside a framebuffer.

I already createt a framebuffer with color565 and I can work with it, but I actually don't find any answers if there is a way to put PNGs inside of framebuffers on ther RPI Pico w.
If anybody knows a way, please help.

(If you are wondering, what is my Plan. I'm rying to have a RPI4 that sends images to the RPI Pico w over UDP socket, so that it will show the Image on a Display)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. You have a PNG in a Pico? In RAM? Saved on the pseudo-disk filesystem? Where did it come from? You want to put it in a framebuffer? Where's the framebuffer - Picos don't have framebuffers as such? What has the RPi4 got to do with it exactly? Please show any/all relevant code. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want to *decode* a PNG file so you can display it? I found a couple of  MicroPython libraries [here](https://github.com/remixer-dec/mpy-img-decoder) and [here](https://github.com/Ratfink/micropython-png/tree/master) for decoding PNG. You might need to adapt one of them to produce the right format for your display. If you need more help, please add more detail to your question.